# VBA Forms.ComboBox not changing on event

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, event-handling

**Description**

I'm not getting my Forms.ComboBox to change on the `Change` event. It seems like the event code doesn't fire. But it does! However, if I **step through** the code, it works perfectly. Can't figure out why this happens.

**What should happen:**

- "CauseBox1" changes (user picks from its drop-down list)
- If the value in CauseBox1 has the word "reason" in it, then "CommentaryBox1" should be enabled. If not, then "CommentaryBox1" should be disabled.
- I'm using a Boolean named `Editing`, which I set to `True` at the beginning of the code (and to `False` at the end of the code). The reason for this is that I'm using MsForms Combobox. Their `Change` event code runs even though `Application.EnableEvents = False`. So it's a precaution for making sure no other `Change` event runs when this one does...

---

```
Private Sub CauseBox1_Change()
  If Editing Then Exit Sub
  Editing = True
  If InStr(1, CauseBox1.Text, "reason") > 0 Then
    If CommentaryBox1.Enabled = False Then CommentaryBox1.Enabled = True
  Else
    If CommentaryBox1.Enabled = True Then CommentaryBox1.Enabled = False
  End If
  Editing = False
 End Sub
```

---

**Here's where it gets wrong:**

- `CauseBox1` changes and "reason" is found within its value
- `CommentaryBox1` **stays disabled**. I can't type in it.
- In order for the `CommentaryBox1` to become enabled, I have to step through the `Change` event code with `F8`. Then it suddenly works.

**Why is this happening? What am I missing?**

**Edit:**
I'm in a Worksheet, not a Userform.

Comment: Add breakpoints and then run the code. See which ones it triggers before it breaks

Comment: I had something similar before where changing Sheets(1) to the name of the sheet fixed it. Hard to say without seeing all the code.

Comment: Just had another thought. Try using Application.ScreenRefresh and seeing if that changes anything.

Comment: How is Editing initially getting passed to your Sub? You didn't put it in as a parameter, nor did you declare it above.

Comment: Are there any events associated with CommentaryBox1? Are these controls in a UserForm, or on the Worksheet surface?

Comment: I finally found what was messing things up. Please see provided answer. Still not sure WHY it happened. If you know, please comment the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a button that cleared all the OLEObjects (ComboBoxes/TextBoxes) in the Worksheet. That code was messing things up. The very last piece of code, `oCommentary1.Object.Enabled = False`, was what created the error. Since I use `Change` events, I don't need to force-disable the `Commentary` boxes. Whenever I change the value (as in above code), the events would fire. I can't really say what's making this error. Is it correct to refer to the MsForms.ComboBox (ActiveX) as an `OLEObject`?

---

```
Public oDate As OLEObject, oAge As OLEObject, oGender As OLEObject, oInitials As OLEObject
Public oCause1 As OLEObject, oCause2 As OLEObject, oCause3 As OLEObject
Public oCommentary1 As OLEObject, oCommentary2 As OLEObject, oCommentary3 As OLEObject

Sub ClearForm()
    With Worksheets("Form")
        Set oDate = .OLEObjects("DateBox")
        Set oInitials = .OLEObjects("InitialBox")
        Set oGender = .OLEObjects("GenderBox")
        Set oAge = .OLEObjects("AgeBox")
        Set oCause1 = .OLEObjects("CauseBox1")
        Set oCause2 = .OLEObjects("CauseBox2")
        Set oCause3 = .OLEObjects("CauseBox3")
        Set oCommentary1 = .OLEObjects("CommentaryBox1")
        Set oCommentary2 = .OLEObjects("CommentaryBox2")
        Set oCommentary3 = .OLEObjects("CommentaryBox3")        
    End With

    oDate.Object.Value = ""
    oInitials.Object.Value = ""
    oGender.Object.Value = ""
    oAge.Object.Value = ""
    oCause1.Object.Value = ""
    oCommentary1.Object.Value = ""
    oCause2.Object.Value = ""
    oCommentary2.Object.Value = ""
    oCause3.Object.Value = ""
    oCommentary3.Object.Value = ""
    oDate.Activate ' Selects the date box

    ' Disables the Commentary Boxes (since the Cause Boxes are empty)
    oCommentary1.Object.Enabled = False
    oCommentary2.Object.Enabled = False
    oCommentary3.Object.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

---